# Не открывается .jar (IDEA IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar

Столкнулся с проблемой при создании .jar в IDEA. Приложение JavaFX.
При запуске джара как-будто ничего не происходит. Поэкспериментировав понял, что проблема в пути к fxml файлу. Такое чувство, что программа при запуске джарника его не находит. Хотя при запуске из самой IntelliJ все хорошо.
Можете посвятить в чем проблема?

**Код:**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/password.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Введите логин и пароль");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Структура проекта:**

[image: Скриншот структуры проекта]

Comment: А fxml в jar попадает?

Comment: Да, попадает. Чтобы легче было увидеть структуру сделал просто е приложение "Привет мир". В ИДЕИ запускается, а с джарника - нет. Пробовал сделать обычный джарник и JavaFXApp.

Comment: Вот ссылка на приложение: <https://yadi.sk/d/jmqbm7BW3A4N5n

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться со статьёй [Как создать краткий, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замени:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/password.fxml"));
```

На:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/marketlite/fxml/password.fxml"));
```

Comment: Если сделать так, то не запускается в самой ИДЕИ. Не может найти по данном пути fxml файл.

Comment: @Dr.Greg вот так все будет работать.Попробуй, я изменил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все работает.